# dynamic pivot table in mysql and join two table

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

i have two table in mysql in the names of dapa_collector_tag_value d and dapa_collector_tag t i want to show dynamic pivot table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAQcr.jpg)

this is my code

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN d.tag_id = ''',
          d.tag_id, ''' THEN d.tag_value ELSE 0 END) AS ''', d.tag_id, '''')
     INTO  @sql
     FROM  dapa_collector_tag_value d
     INNER JOIN  dapa_collector_tag t  ON d.tag_id = t.id;


SET @sql = CONCAT(
      'SELECT  d.effective_date, ', @sql, ' ', 
         'FROM dapa_collector_tag_value d ',
         'INNER   JOIN  dapa_collector_tag t  ON d.tag_id = t.id ',
         'GROUP BY d.effective_date'
                 );
PREPARE stmt  FROM  @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

i have error SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
   for the right syntax to use
   near 'FROM dapa_collector_tag_value d
    INNER JOIN  dapa_collector_tag t  ON d.tag_id = t.' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Subqueries need to be in parens:  `( SELECT ... )`.
- Your code needs to be inside a `Stored Procedure`; let's see the whole SP.
- Please use `{}` for formatting code, not `"`.
- `INTO NULL` does not make sense.